# How smooth can this be?

Tags: nt.number-theory, smoothness

If $a$ is an even integer then how smooth can $a^2-1$ be?

Approximately how many integers in $a\in[0,t]$ are there such that $a^2-1$ is $k$-smooth?

Comment: The numbers of $prime(i)$-smooth $4n^2-1$'s for $n \le 10^6$ start
$0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 15, 22, 35, 56, 76$ (i.e. there is one $3$-smooth, namely $n=1$, there are three $5$-smooth (including $n=2$ and $13$), etc).  This sequence does not seem to be in OEIS.

Comment: Since $a^2-1$ is $k$-smooth if and only if $a-1,a+1$ are $k$-smooth, the latter question is almost answered by Stormer's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem , which gives a bound exponential in $\pi(k)$.  Presumably the proof of that theorem adapts to numbers separated by 2 rather than 1.

Comment: There is a PDF of Klazar from 2010 on this topic, which covers the case of smooth numbers differing by 2.  It should come up in a search on Stormers Theorem.  Gerhard "Is Typographically Challenged At Present" Paseman, 2020.07.05.

Comment: Referring theorem $1$ in http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~klazar/stormer.pdf?

Comment: $26^2-1$ is $5$-smooth, $244^2-1$ is $7$-smooth, $1574^2-1$ is $13$-smooth.